# Prawn - NoMethodError: private method `p' called for object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, prawn

I'm trying to generate a pdf and for some reason i keep getting a no method error when i try to render the pdf. Literally no idea what to do as all i'm trying at this point is to render a blank pdf.

```
NoMethodError: private method `p' called for #<OrderPdfCreator:0x007f9365053a20>
```

**OrderController**

```
require 'order_pdf_creator'

  def print_store_invoice
    # print the store invoice...
    @order = Order.find_by_id(params[:id])
    # create the pdf
    pdf = OrderPdfCreator.new(@order)

    render :attachment => pdf.p, :filename => "#{@order.id}.pdf", :layout => false
  end
```

**OrderPdfCreator.rb**

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'open-uri'

class OrderPdfCreator < BasePdfCreator

  def initialize(order)

    @pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => 'A4')
    @pdf.font_size = 14
    @order_pdf = order

    file_path = File.join(Rails.root,'tmp',"#{@order_pdf.id}.pdf")
    p = File.open(file_path, 'wb') { |f| f.puts @pdf.render }

  end

end
```

**BasePdfCreator.rb**

```
# encoding: UTF-8
class BasePdfCreator

  private

  def blank_line
    @pdf.text ' '
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all. You are calling a method you shouldn't. Specifically in this line:

```
render :attachment => pdf.p, :filename => "#{@order.id}.pdf", :layout => false
```

Change it to:

```
render :attachment => pdf, :filename => "#{@order.id}.pdf", :layout => false
```

And in your initialize method, change:

```
p = File.open(file_path, 'wb') { |f| f.puts @pdf.render }
```

to:

```
@pdf
```

Rails (well, ruby) always returns the result of the last statement in a method (at least by default).

**EDIT**

Ok, so I see what's happening. I personally would rename the `initialize` method to something else (say `createPDF`) so it returns the prawn document object and not a `OrderPdfCreator` object. So in your controller you would have:

```
pdf = OrderPdfCreator.new
pdf.createPDF
send_data pdf.render, :type => 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'
```

Comment: ah yes cool thanks. missed that. It now searches for a `print_store_invoice` template and i have one in the location it searches for but doesn't seem to be able to find it. I would also think that telling it to render the attachment and layout false would prevent searching for a template?

Comment: When I use prawn, my call is: `send_data pdf,
                    :type => 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'`. The `disposition: 'inline'` makes sure it displays in the same window/tab and not a new popup.

Comment: great, that's gotten me closer but now when it tries to render the pdf it says 'failed to load pdf document'. There are no errors in the log.

Comment: Ok changed my answer a bit. You don't need to open a file. Just to send the prawn document. That should work.

Comment: hmmm same thing still happens

Comment: Sorry, change `send_data` line to `send_data pdf.render, :type => 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'`. I forgot to have you render the document!

Comment: that gives `undefined method 'render' for #<OrderPdfCreator:0x007faf0c5d0198>`

Comment: ok i've figured it out...i just needed to call `@pdf.render` within another method and then call that method on `pdf` in the controller. Thanks for you help

Comment: Yeah I just changed my answer to say that. Hope everything works out.